Guy steals a car with a driver in it and goes back to the hood
I saw this movie a long time ago, so maybe it was made in the 1990s or early 2000-2007, or earlier.

In it the guy steals a car, with a driver in it takes him back to where he is from.
The carjacker is white and lives in an african american part of the city.
The carjacker steals cars for a living, I think.
The carjacker tells the guy he has cancer, and dies from a gunshot wound, I think in the end.
The carjacker's name is blue, I think I couldn't find the character on IMDb it might be wrong.
There is a scene where the carjacker drops the wallet or a watch from the guy into an oil barrel or something.
The guy who got kidnapped has moustache, I think.
The carjacker wears a hood.

What's the name of this movie?

"The guy who got kidnapped has moustache" = completely useless info but I think it's great that you added it. :)

Sounds like Michael Cimino's Sunchaser from 1996 with Woody Harrelson and Jon Seda:

"Blue" Monroe (played by Seda) is a 16-year-old juvenile offender (convicted of murdering an abusive stepfather) who is dying of abdominal cancer. Dr. Michael Reynolds (played by Harrelson) is Blue's rich, self-absorbed oncologist.
During a medical visit, [Blue] discovers that he has only a month to live and decides to escape. He kidnaps Dr. Reynolds and forces him to drive to Arizona to visit a mountain lake sacred to the Navajo people. The trip forces both to confront their sense-of-self and life choices.

Harrelson has a moustache and Seda wears a black knit cap throughout. Sadly, this critical and commercial failure was the last feature length film of the once-great Cimino. Here's the trailer:



